# How to reset the ordering of columns with bootstrap 3 at extrasmall screens with preserving showed html markup?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

Here is the html code what is:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">Content</div>
<aside class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">Some aside text</aside>
```

At extrasmall screens main content goes first before the aside section. But how to make it go first and the aside element second preserving initial html markup and only at an extrasmall screens? and all columns must to occupy all sreen width at extrasmall devices

Answer (score 1):

Added a custom class `up-xs` and `down-xs` for the two div's and set the xs width condition using media-query.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-9 down-xs">Content</div>
 <aside class="col-md-3 up-xs">Some aside text</aside>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media ( max-width: 480px ) {
 .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
 }

 .up-xs {
  order: 1;
 }

 .down-xs {
  order: 2;
 }
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/fBWjz1qVxi)

Comment: Hello. thank you. I checked the behavior of your code but it works not exactly I need. At attached image you can see what i need to see at extrasmall devices http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0522/h_1432306626_9741399_f0073b56ab.jpg But in html code aside element should go right after the main content section

Comment: Oh ok, but `make it go right after the aside element` I mistook that you needed to make that right :P I will correct the code.

Comment: Hello, Kumar. Thank you. You helped me to find the right code, here it's:

Comment: I don't get it Boris.

Comment: Hello @Manoj!
I found out that at my mobile browsers(Chrome 18.0.1025314 and built-in Android 4.0.4 browser) your code doesn't work. Is due to its backwardness? Does my mobile browsers not know about flex? How to solve my task for this browsers?

Comment: @BorisGarkoun Unfortunately, Flexbox is not supported in older browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: And you cannot reorder a 12 column grid class using `push` and `pull`.

Comment: So it's better to reorder elements in html therefore inspite of SEO priority. Yes?

Comment: Yes, reorder it in HTML. I am not a SEO expert. So can't really comment on that. But it doesn't make much difference to SEO, does it?